# Where is the carrier bird in the Soviet Installation?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I missed the dialogue for the Misguided Intelligence mission and I only have a vague marker on my map. How can I identify this bird and continue with the mission? The best I've found online is that it flies around the lumber mill. The one in the middle of the map? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overworld map won't be helpful here. Instead **go into the glowing things mode** (right thumbstick) and green concentric circles will show around the bird when it appears on-screen. Mine was sitting on a structure in-between the main base camp and the mill.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the building which a truck is packing there. Climb up to the top level near the communication tower and a rode beside. press the RS button and look down at red star signboard, a carrier bird is sitting at it. SHOOT IT to complete the mission.