# How do you find the carrier bird?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

The game is 99.99% finished. Every site is 100% completed: documents, relics etc. The only thing not done, is the side mission to shoot the carrier bird.

I ran past the gate where it is located, when the mission started. It probably flew away. Now, even when using survival instincts, where green concentric circles should appear, no green highlighted bird can be found. I've walked around the main building, with the truck in front, and I've gone up the mountain, to the radio on top that you should destroy. However, wherever I look there's no bird.

To enlarge my search area, I have been into the copper mill and up the hill towards the prison. Has anyone got any clue as to where the missing bird could be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the carrier bird in the Soviet Installation?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243097/where-is-the-carrier-bird-in-the-soviet-installation)

Comment: @SysDragon Your proposed duplicate would not help OP solve their problem. Per [Duplicate Questions: A Trial](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11895), I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 1):

It is sitting on the arch of a building just northeast of the base camp where Jacob gives you your first optional mission. The Arch faces east and runs north-south, its white with a red star in the middle. The crow is sitting right above the star. If you approach it carefully you can shoot the crow before he takes off, miss and youll have to track him down.

Here is a video for your viewing pleasure.

The bird will stay in the zone, so you don't have to enlarge your search any further than the map says within the zone in which the quest was given.

Comment: Actually, there was a bug in the game which stopped my from completing this mission. Meanwhile the bug is fixed and you can find the bird again in the way you describe.